# How I check if the user is an ADMIN

Tags: codeigniter-3

**Hello guys**

I'm trying to create a function that allows the user to connect as admin, or simple user by creating a column in the users table called (is_adminn) as INT.
for the moment i'm doing it in a static way :

```
   function _check_admin_login($username, $pword)
{

    $target_username="firas";
    $target_pass="password";

    if(($username==$target_username) && ($pword==$target_pass)){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }


    }
```

and then i will call it in the admin controller :

```
function username_check($str){


$this->load->module('store_accounts');
$this->load->module('site_security');
$error_msg = "Vous avez saisi un nom d'utilisateur ou un mot de passe incorrecte";

$pword = $this->input->post('pword', TRUE);

 $result = $this->site_security->_check_admin_login($str, $pword);
if($result==FALSE){

  $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', $error_msg);
        return FALSE;
}else{
    return TRUE;
}



}
```

I did many tests like if the value of is_adminn is equal to 1 , it returns True

```
function _check_admin_login($username, $pword)
{
  $this->load->module('store_accounts');
  $this->store_accounts->fetch_data_from_db();
  $is_adminn = $data['is_adminn'];


if($is_adminn==1){
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do what you want, first time check if the username and the password matches and after that check is the user id have the status is_admin 1.

model

```
public function check_admin($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('id' => $id, 'is_admin' => 1 ));
    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

controller

```
$data['temp'] = $this->User_model->get_id_by_email($data['login']['email']);
$data['user'] = $this->User_model->check_login($data['login']['email'], $data['login']['password']);
if ($data['user'] && $this->Admin_model->check_admin($data['temp'][0]['id'])) {
    $session_data = array(
    //what you wanna store in session
    );
```